# not able to use messagelistener() using xmpp and smack android

Tags: android, xmpp, listener

```
Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat(userToSend , new MessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message   ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);

    }
});
```

it does not allow me to use messageListener() instead it prompts me to use ChatMessageListener(). I am using smack and xmpp to create a chat application in android please help.

Comment: You you don't want to use ChatMessageListener because?

Comment: i am using chatMessageListener but it it not being called any idea why? just replace the above code where there is MessageListener

Comment: @Flow I got the same problem, or a similar problem. From my experiences ChatManager does not work correct. I´ve implemented both, ChatManager with Listener and StanzaListener, as I receive stanzas on StanzaListener, ChatManager does not show any incoming message. But I know from the StanzaListener, that I get some. The next problem: With the first Chat I can receive messages with the ChatManager, but allways the first message does not work until receiver sends some message too. Then, after some time, the connection and authentication is ok, but the connection between chat members get lost...

Comment: This would be a new question, or even better, just join #smack (freenode). I assume you simply aren't familiar with the logic of ChatManager.

Comment: I followed the examples at Smack API, so I think it should work...